# PHP word comparison and weighting

Tags: php, function, strpos

I am currently writing a search match for a project I am working on.  As part of the search I will use a wide mixture of exact keyword, phrase and other metrics to provide a weighted score for the search results.

The aim being to allow comparison of word a to word/string b and provide a weighted score returned. so an exact match would provide 100%.

This score then become part of a bigger math function so search match accuracy isn't purely based on this (just in case that is the impression), this is only about the relative weight on the matches shown.

```
function search_match($a, $b, $s, $audit = 0)   /* a = needle, b = haystack, $s = score, adit allow print of match type*/
    {
        $a = strtolower($a);
        $b = strtolower($b);

        $c = explode(' ', $a);
        $d = explode(' ', $b);

        if  ( $a === $b )           {                   $s = $s;        $t='Equal match';       }
        else if ( $a == $b )            {                   $s = $s * 0.9;  $t='Almost equal match';        }
        else if (metaphone($a)==metaphone($b)){                 $s = $s * 0.75; $t='Metaphone match';       }           /* word structure matching */
        else if ( levenshtein($a, $b) == 0  )   {                   $s = $s * 0.7;  $t='Levenshtein';           }           /* Typo capture*/
        else if ( strpos($a,$b) !== false )     {                   $s = $s * 0.6;  $t='A in B';            }
        else if ( strpos($b,$a) !== false )     {                   $s = $s * 0.5;  $t='B in A';            }
        else if ( is_array($d) && in_array($a , $d)) {                  $s = $s * 0.4;  $t='Part of A in part of B';        }
        else if ( is_array($c) && in_array($b , $c)) {                  $s = $s * 0.3;  $t='Part of B in part of A';        }
        else                    {                   $s = 0;     $t='No match';          }   
        return ($audit===1)? $t:$s;
    }
```

So, I'm looking for some support to refine this, specifically:
1. Would you agree with the score ratio applied in relation to the relevance of the match?
2. Can you suggest any additional criteria to match OR a better order for those matches.

My hope with this is to provide a good word matching function that can be used beyond my project, I've seen similar snippets on here with strops etc but nothing which actually 'weights' the match.

**Edits:**

1. Missed if no match 0.... Doh
2. Added metaphone and Levenshtein weighting as recommended by @Fatfreddy
3. Added option to return text of match type for visability of how scoring is computed.  Just pass audit = 1 for text return of match.

Comment: have you read about the onboard tools for php ? e.g. http://php.net/manual/de/function.levenshtein.php , and http://php.net/manual/de/function.metaphone.php . or a combination of that 2 functions: use the metaphone of 2 strings and compare the levenshtein distance ?

Comment: Personally, instead of using a lot of `else if` I'd have each statement as an `if` such that a perfect match will still get max points but you might get a higher score if the string is at the start of the haystack. It might lead to better scores than 100, 90, 80 or however you're doing it.

Comment: _words in italic_ are lighter of course. just passing by :)

Comment: @FatFreddy, nice, thanks.  No I hadn't encountered those before, I will integrate, thanks

Comment: @sdexp, I have that within the main scoring.  Basically, matches are assigned a maximum score (includes location, categories, distance and lots of other elements).  Depending on importance, each score is defined (say 5 points).  That 5 points max then goes through the function (so further refining takes place depending on matched criteria).  The aim is to have search results with a more refined weighting, its easy to do 100%, 90% and so on.  everything bar 100% is always academic but I feel it worthwhile to add some depth to the result weighting.

Answer (score 1):

Refer levenshtein algo

[levenshtein Github](https://github.com/tdebatty/php-language-processing)

[PHP levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/de/function.levenshtein.php)

[PHP Language Processing](https://github.com/dineshghule321/php-language-processing)

[PHP Similar Text Library](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

[PHP Bishops Github Library](https://github.com/bishopb/pattern)

```
$a = 'How are you?'; // simple word matching in PHP
        if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
            echo 'true';
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the refs Dinesh, @Fatfreddy already suggested those.  strops is already integrated

Comment: @Pete-iCalculator sounds good.. check other references also they will help you in some cases